# How to pass other parameters onchange of dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to hit an action on change of Html.DropDownList. I am able to pass the selected value but I need help passing other parameters like Model properties to the js function that gets called onchange of dropdown. Here is my code

```
@(Html.DropDownList("productSelected", Model.ProductList,
                        new { onchange= "refreshQueueByPageSize(this.value)" }))
```

I want to do something like

```
@(Html.DropDownList("productSelected", Model.ProductList,
                        new { onchange= "refreshQueueByPageSize(this.value, Model.ProductType)" }))
```

but doing it this way I get errors while sending the additional parameters to the js function(refreshQueueByPageSize)

Answer (score 0):

You can get `Model.ProductType` in js function with `@Model.ProductType`,so you don't need to pass it to the function:

js:

```
function refreshQueueByPageSize(value)
{
   var ProductType=@Model.ProductType;
}
```

**Update:**

If you want to pass c# variable to onchange,try to use:

```
@Html.DropDownList("productSelected", l,
                        new { @onchange= "refreshQueueByPageSize(this.value,'"+Model.ProductType+"')" })
```

Comment: This is a work around, but what if the function call is in a for loop and I want to send dynamic data?

Comment: Hi,I have updated my answer with  passing c# variable to onchange.